# integrating security for user objects in swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am relatively new to iOS software development.
I am trying to add security for user objects in my parse app.
But have no idea on how to add it to the project.

Should it be like this?

```
func logInViewController() {
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("myname", password: "mypass") {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            // Do stuff after successful login.

            let user = PFUser.logInWithUsername("my_username", password: "my_password")
            user.username = "my_new_username" // attempt to change username
            user.save() // This succeeds, since the user was authenticated on the device.

            // Get the user from a non-authenticated method.
            let query = PFUser.query()
            let userAgain = query!.getObjectWithId(user.objectId!) as! PFUser

            userAgain.username = "another_username"

            // This will crash, sinse the PFUser is not authenticated
            userAgain.save()

        } else {
            // The login failed. Check error to see why.

        }
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        if currentUser != nil {
            // Do stuff with the user
        } else {
            // Show the signup or login screen.
        }
    }
}
```

or like this?

```
func userOnlyNameChange() {
    let user = PFUser.logInWithUsername("my_username", password: "my_password")
    user.username = "my_new_username" // attempt to change username
    user.save() // This succeeds, since the user was authenticated on the device.

    // Get the user from a non-authenticated method.
    let query = PFUser.query()
    let userAgain = query!.getObjectWithId(user.objectId!) as! PFUser

    userAgain.username = "another_username"

    // This will crash, sinse the PFUser is not authenticated
    userAgain.save()
}
```

or have I just done it completely wrong?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do...

Comment: @Wain have a look [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-security-for-user-objects) under "Security for User objects"

Comment: @TimmyT it's unclear what you are asking. If both mentioned approaches work, then choose the one you're more comfortable with. If one of them doesn't work and you'd like to use it, let us know what problems you run into.